# How do I get the right most 3 characters of the formula and not the value of the cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a formula in excel like this in a particular cell:

```
='Total Statistics Report'!V351
```

How do I get the right most 3 characters of the formula and not the value of the cell?

So the answer I am looking for is:

```
351
```

The answer I am getting is `431` which is what I would expect from this value `0.983545574652431` but I am interested in the formula.

Can this be done?

Note: Press CTRL + ` (grave accent) toggles between formulas and values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2013, then consider the function =FORMULATEXT()

Comment: sorry should have stated on excel 2010, tks

Comment: Then you would use a **VBA UDF** to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple `UDF`

Call it like
`=GetFormula('Total Statistics Report'!V351)`

*code*

```
Function GetFormula(rng1 As Range) As String
If rng1.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Len(rng1.Formula) >= 3 Then
        GetFormula = Right$(rng1.Cell.Formula, 3)
    Else
        GetFormula = "too short"
    End If
Else
   GetFormula = "Invalid range"
End If
End Function
```

Comment: How do i call it like this `=GetFormula('Total Statistics Report'!V351)`? I'curently calling it like `=GetFormula(C359)` but don't think its the same